# TypeError: Cannot read property 'load' of undefined at cc.resources

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-js, cocoscreator

When I try to use `cc.resources.load(arg1, arg2)`, I get this error:

> `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'load' of undefined`

As far as I know, it is a built-in Cocos Creator class and the [documentation](https://docs.cocos.com/creator/manual/en/scripting/load-assets.html) itself says to use it. When I try to call `cc.log(cc.resources)`, it shows `undefined` in the console. A folder called "resources" exists in my project and it's not empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cc.resources` isn't available in Cocos Creator 2.3.3, only 2.4.

The solution is to use the function `cc.loader.loadRes`.